# How to generate new CSRF Token for each user request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im suppose to generate new CSRF token for each request user make. I do understand this technique is not good and it wont allow user to make simultaneous request. But still I wish to implement it.

I have override function **addCookieToResponse** in **Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken**. By adding **$request->session()->regenerateToken()**.

```
protected function addCookieToResponse($request, $response)
{
    $config = config('session');
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    $response->headers->setCookie(
        new Cookie(
            'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), $this->availableAt(60 * $config['lifetime']),
            $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], $config['http_only'], false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
        )
    );

    return $response;
}
```

The token keep changing but during POST request I receive TokenMismatchExcemption due to **csrf_token()** token to be old.It seems crsf_token() is called before addCookieToResponse(). Is there any better way to implement this technique?

Comment: This is because, the POST request will also generate a new Token. I am curious as to why you would want to do this anyway?

Comment: @Mozammil due to certain security request I have to implement this. Knowing more about it will cause further complication and misunderstanding. Just need way to go forward with it

Answer (score 0):

Well its a bit weird what you're trying to achieve but i think about this like an after middleware:

```
$response = $next($request); // process petition

$request->session()->regenerateToken(); // regenerate token

return $response; // send response
```

Please share the result

Comment: It does not work. Same error thrown by  TokenMismatchExcemption